# dynamiclly change pages with slug and include tag in template

Tags: django, templates, url, include, slug

I was trying to build a template preview in my website, which is when user click the specific template preview on the templates list page, it will direct to the template detail page, the urls.py code is like below:

urls.py:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('choose_templates/<slug:slug>/', views.template_preview, name='template_preview'),
]
```

views.py:

```
def template_preview(request,slug):
    context = {
        'slug':slug
    }
    return render(request,'./html/htmlbase.html',context)
```

htmlbase.html:

```html
{% include slug %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

what I want to do is when user clicks on the different template preview buttons, it will direct to the corresponding template detail page. the code above result in " TemplateDoesNotExist".

Could anyone help me with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Before moving on, your problem sounds like you didn't configure your templates directory correctly. Conventionally, you want to add this to your settings.py (although there should be an empty list there):

```py
# settings.py

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),], # this line!
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            # ... some options here ...
        },
    },
]
```

and then if you put any of your templates inside a folder named `templates`, Django will automatically look for it.

More information on [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/)

Comment: yes, I had my template setting correctly, if replace "{% include slug %}" to "{% include './demo_template.html' %}", it works just fine.

Comment: To me, `./html/htmlbase.html` still looks fishy. What is the dot doing there?

Comment: assume all the template setting is working, do you have any suggestion about how can I bound slug with specific template content with {% include variable %} in the base template? I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Something like `{% url 'profile' slug=user.slug %}`?

Comment: Do you have any idea that if I am using only one template and update the whole page of content in that  template follow different slug?

Comment: With the same url, say, `/profile/user/1` and `/profile/user/2` (1 and 2 are the slugs), they still **belong to the same view** and therefore everything in the page will change accordingly to the new slug (assuming that you rendered the context properly).

Comment: cool! will try that out , Thank you for you suggestion!

Comment: By the way, remember to pass in the url as something like (urls.py) `path('profile/user/<slug:slug>', ...)` don't hardcode things. Documentation available [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#example).